# SQL Server Count - Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have a table contain records as per below image. I want to do a count for each status and am able to do that by selecting each type of status. Which I will needs to exec 4 query to get the result. I would like to know how can I achieve that by using single query statement? Any advices or suggestion is welcome and highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Table Records]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE(NO,STATUS)AS
(
   SELECT 1,'OPEN' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'OPEN'UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,'BILLED'UNION ALL
   SELECT 4,'CANCELLED'UNION ALL
   SELECT 5,'BILLING'UNION ALL
   SELECT 6,'BILLED'UNION ALL
   SELECT 7,'CANCELLED'UNION ALL
   SELECT 8,'BILLING'UNION ALL
   SELECT 9,'CONFIRM'UNION ALL
   SELECT 10,'IN PROGRESS'UNION ALL
   SELECT 11,'OPEN'UNION ALL
   SELECT 12,'CONFIRM' 
)
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='BILLED'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS BILLED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='BILLING'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS BILLING,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='CANCELLED'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS CANCELLED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS NOT IN ('CANCELLED','BILLING','BILLED')THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS UNBILL
FROM CTE AS C
```

CTE is an example you have provided. Please replace reference to it with reference to your table

Comment: Thanks Sergey for fast response and working solution. Really appreciated that. Tqvm